# How to reopen question that was marked as duplicate but it is clearly not a duplicate

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

The question below was marked as a duplicate. However, it is very clear based on the comments associated with the question I posted that my question is not the same as to what it is marked as.

[What to do as a Dev when for years their team has lacked product innovation, not used project mgmt methodologies, and kept bad Software Dev practices?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198767/what-to-do-as-a-dev-when-for-years-their-team-has-lacked-product-innovation-not)

*This question already has an answer here: How should I behave as a developer in a project that's headed for failure? 20 answers*

Those answers in the other post do not address my question. Who is going to leave a company just because a project is failing? It does not make any sense, so whoever marked my question as duplicate is clearly not attention to detail.

**I already left a note in the question but it is still marked as duplicate**

*Note: I have read [[How should I behave as a developer in a project that's headed for failure? 20 answers]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197650/how-should-i-behave-as-a-developer-in-a-project-thats-headed-for-failure), but the answers do not address the points on this question. If you look at the answers I've received, the answers are totally different to the ones posted on that other question. For example, who is going to leave a company just because 1 project is failing? It does not make any sense, so whoever marked my question as duplicate is clearly not attention to detail.

To those who have marked this question as duplicate: The answers on that post do not address my question, unlike the ones on this post that do address my question directly. Please don't mark something as a duplicate if it isn't, because then people stop looking at it. Also, that question is just about 1 project failing. My question is about all projects, the product and a team that has been doing the same for years and that continuing to do so will eventually lead to failure of whole team and product.*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @gnat, thanks for that post, is very useful.

Comment: @gnat , I added the comment by following your advice, but it was deleted. so what is the point of this meta?http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/198767/revisions

Comment: well most likely reviewers didn't found your explanation of the differences convincing. Actually the way you presented these, makes me wonder that 3 of them _were_ convinced (your question shows 3 reopen votes to me). Look, explanation is expected to look a natural part of your researc, not as appeal to readers please-reopen. Meta fluff like "This is NOT a duplicate of the other question. Stop flagging this! ...whoever marked my question as duplicate..." just has no place in a question...

Comment: ...Programmers is a Q&A site, not a forum - no wonder that one of the readers just rolled back all your edits, with meta fluff and with relevant explanation of the differences

Comment: @gnat I updated comment, please see above, and left the comment just basic as recommended in the post you sent me. "*Note: I have read [How should..........         .........of whole team and product.*" is that comment good?

Answer (score 3):

I just took a look at both questions - I don't see any duplication. However, I'm not sure that your question should stay open - it's incredibly broad. There are [many books written on improving software processes and project management](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Asoftware+process+improvement&keywords=software+process+improvement&ie=UTF8&qid=1396203241&rnid=2941120011).

Comment: It is an issue that occurs in lots companies, even people complain about same issue in glassdoor reviews, some companies disappear from market due to not addressing these issues on time etc..so what a better place to ask this question and get useful feedback than here at programmers.stackexchange.com where is the expert community of programmers.

Comment: @DiM This type of question is very much on-topic. However, you are asking a lot in this one question. We provide a [definition of too broad](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) which states that "if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format". This particular question has answers, so it's hard to narrow without invalidating answers. However, I would recommend starting to research methods of implementing process changes and then asking more specific questions about things that you don't understand.

Comment: I was just asking for feedback from people who have been in the same situation with real examples, and have many years of experience by working at different companies, and know whether is worth to go one way or the other. The answers to this question will be very valuable to tons of programmers who are in same situation, and which is why there is so high turn over at some companies. I have not seen a book that concentrates on this subject.

Comment: @DiM Posting on Meta is the right thing to do to see what the rest of the community says (it may take a day or two - we're typically more active during the work week than on weekends), but I honestly don't see a way that I can justify reopening that question as it stands right now. There are many books on the subject that should serve as a starting point and if you're just looking for opinions and discussion, then the main site isn't the place to go (for that I'd recommend stopping by our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), which is more active during the week).

Comment: This type of question really has an answer especially if multiple experts on the subject end up indicating that the best route to go is : route A. chat does not really help on this case, as what I'm looking for are serious answers with depth. what books on the subject are you referring to? As you said, "Meta is the right thing to do to see what the rest of the community says", which is  why I posted the question here because I thought the same.

Comment: @DiM My answer here has a link to an Amazon search for books on "software process improvement" as a sample. Searching for books, blogs, presentations, and other content using that phrase or "software project management" should yield many resources.

Comment: I saw the amazon books you posted, thanks for that info, but that's not really how things work at companies, and that does not really help. Yes ideal is use project management methodologies, doing things right way etc... but it is the "ideal", that does not happen most of the time, otherwise all companies would be lala lands and perfection. However, getting answers from experts in the programmers community who have been in same situations is worth more than a 300+ pages theory book about software process improvement.

Comment: I mean that's why these stack exchange forums are open, and that's the main point of an expert community, otherwise all answers would say, go find X book at amazon.

Comment: @DiM You may also be interested in concepts like "continuous improvement". About half of my work life is process improvement and continuous improvement, so I'm pretty confident in saying that you should study the ideal state and tailor it as necessary for your organization. Many good books will also contain case studies. Some places even have case studies and such online if you don't want to buy books. You may also misunderstand what Stack Exchange is for - we deal in solutions to specific problems, not extended discussions, opinions, or extremely long answers that are better covered in books.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Couldn't agree more with your statement to study the ideal and tailor to reality.  Now the ensuing depression that comes from studying the ideal and realizing that your current work environment is more likely to be incinerated by cosmic rays than adopt specific process improvements is a different problem entirely :)

Comment: @ThomasOwens Why are you putting "put on hold as too broad by Thomas Owens" ? There were 3 votes to reopen question as mentioned above, and it is not too broad, as other have left answers already. I followed all the advice from gnat to reopen question as mentioned in another meta post. your answer here is not useful at all, as reading books is not going to solve issue!